# Limit flickr JSON image number?

Tags: image, json, limit, flickr

I tried this URL and it works fine...

http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?per_page=6&jsoncallback=?

...almost. It is set to "per_page=6" but it don't listen to it. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this URL does not accept any limit.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra question mark at the end. Can you remove the last parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately according to the API this isn't supported

http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/groups_pool/

I was in need of it as well